# Just a little confusion about Facebook Chat in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, pidgin, facebook-chat

[Facebook deprecated their XMPP Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat) for whatever evil business reasons they had. As their documentation and various [blog posts](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working) or even [StackExchange questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645920/cant-log-in-to-facebook-accounts-using-pidgin) say, accessing Facebook Chat in that way became impossible. I found that out myself too as my Pidgin at work stopped working with my Facebook account.

Now comes the strange part: at home, Thunderbird still can connect to my Facebook account. As far as I could Google [Thunderbird also uses XMPP to communicate with Facebook servers, and they don't have plans (or time and manpower) to change this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2927309). How is this possible? How is Thunderbird different that it still can connect to Facebook?

Comment: And now Thunderbird suddenly seems to have stopped working also. Does anyone know what changed?

Comment: @Draconis: I still got a Facebook message in Thunderbird last night.

Comment: Very strange. I wonder what is happening then...